# Outputting inputted text in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Why is this not working:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private EditText Name;
    private TextView output;

    public void buttonOnClick(View v){
        Button button = (Button) v;
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        output.setText(Name.getText());
    }
}
```

It doesn't give an error either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private EditText Name;
    private TextView output;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
                output.setText(Name.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you use this code with multiple buttons by just adding more onclicklisteners for each button and a different public void for each?

Comment: Yes you should assign an onclicklistener to every button. Alternatively, you can also implement onclicklistener and use a single onclick method for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you passed buttonOnClick method in onClick tag of button in activity_main.xml ?
like android:onClick="buttonOnClick".

Please share your activity_main.xml file.